# Where did the "sync" button go in iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes

Ever since it supported devices, iTunes has had a "sync" button, which seems to have vanished from version 11. Where did it go? How do I sync my iOS devices with iTunes now?

Comment: There was no reason to remove the 'Sync' button. I have to admit that I really hate it when software engineers change something just to justify their hours. Keeping software easy to use should be job #1. Before, I could download new podcasts and then click the sync button, now I have to close and restart iTunes or unplug and replug in my ipod - wastefull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's there, it just goes away sometimes.

While the "Sync" button used to be reliably present in the same location in iTunes 10, it — as well as others — now vanishes occasionally in what (presumably) is a context sensitive manner.

Answer (score 8):

The sync button is on the bottom right of the iTunes window when you are viewing a device.

[image: sync button location in iTunes]

Connect a device or two, and you will see controls to click in the top right to view the iOS device. Also option-command-s will toggle the traditional sidebar - now with more color than (immediately) before.

[image: iTunes sync]

Selecting the device will bring up a mostly familiar interface. You can also search on sync in the iTunes help menu. This update has changed the default views to look flatter and focus more directly on one main view, but menu commands, key commands and buttons are there to get to sync settings as usual.

Comment: I see what happened: it's gone until "apply" is clicked.

Comment: BTW, what are you highlighting your screen captures with? That's way better than most.

Comment: I use Skitch v 1.0.12 as the new version gives me hives (a little). I'm not sure you can get that version unless you had purchased it from the Mac App Store (free) before it was [updated to v2.x](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/skitch/id425955336?mt=12). I really like how fast it lets me document things with shadows, crops, annotations and then to upload elsewhere.

Comment: You know, either I blew past it *really fast*, or I didn't get one...