# iTunes Sync Problem with iPhone 5

Tags: iphone

I just got my iPhone 5, and I installed iTunes 11.01. When I connect my iPhone via USB to my laptop, it just charges. Nothing happens with iTunes nor with my iPhone.
I restarted the iTunes and my iPhone too, but nothing happened.

Is there another program like iTunes for iPhone to download songs?

Comment: Perhaps you should take a loot at [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/73212/21487)?

Answer (score 1):

Open iTunes, go into preferences, Devices tab , and make sure that the prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically! Checkbox is not checked